# fql.query is returning the empty array when i try to select the photos and albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query',
                                'query'=>'SELECT src_big, pid, src 
                                            FROM photo 
                                           WHERE owner = "$user_id" '));
print_r($friends)
```

Please advise me... I want the select to get the photos and albums and comment, recent updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the photos you need first to select the albums. Try it:

```
SELECT src_big, pid, src FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = "$user_id")
```

Comment: THanks..it works but when i but the coding like this ...SELECT src_big, pid, src FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = "$user_id")
. Again it displays the empty array. If i put the me() instead of the $user_id. then it works for me.

Comment: @ananth can you please mail me full code for getting albums using gragh api...i have tried many ways...but my query returns only empty array .thanks in advance.jafar@masteroe.in

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above: Permission to photos is also required: if you have only user_photos, you cannot query the friend's photos etc. So request user permissions:

```
"user_photos","friends_photos"
```

as described in
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/